# How to use field of cross-object query to assign some value to it?

Tags: apex, soql

This is the query I am using:

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT (SELECT AccountId FROM OpenActivities) FROM Account];
```

I have to assign some value to AccountId field of open activity records.

```
for(Account acc: accList) 
{
   acc.accountId = masterAccId; 
}
```

masterAccId is account id of some other account. But acc.accountId is not possible as it is not the field of account, instead it is of OpenActivity field.

Comment: You need to iterate over the OpenActivities inside the iteration of the account. I am a bit confused though as the AccountId is already populated with the AccountId of the account to which they are related. Where are you getting the value of the `materAccId`? You are going to have to expand a bit on the details

Comment: I have to build a functionality to merge accounts, so I want to transfer open activities of slave account to master account. masterAccId is the id of that master account and the actual query will be:
`List<Account> accList = [SELECT (SELECT AccountId FROM OpenActivities) FROM Account where id IN :slaveIds];`

Comment: `for(Account acc : accList) 
{
   for(OpenActivity oa : acc) 
  { 
   oa.AccountId = masterAccId; 
  } 
}` I have tried this, but getting error : Field is not writeable: OpenActivity.AccountId

Comment: When you merge accounts the activities merge along with them. No need to manually set to me account id AFAIK. But it's been w while since I have actually done it

Comment: I have made a custom solution for merging, I don't think it will move automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the child related list, not the parent list. In this case, the type could be `Event` *or* `Task`, so just use `SObject` as your loop variable type.

```
List<SObject> openActivities = new List<SObject>();
for (Account parent : [SELECT (SELECT Id FROM OpenActivities) FROM Account WHERE ...])
{
    for (SObject child : parent.OpenActivities)
    {
        child.put('AccountId', masterAccountId);
        openActivities.add(child);
    }
}
openActivities.sort();
update openActivities;
```

Calling `sort` before you operate on this list will be critical in this functionality working if you have any amount of mixing between the two activity types. When operating on a list of multiple object types, you can only have ten alternating chunks of object type before you will get an error. See also:

> **[Creating Records for Different Object Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm)**
>
> You can create records for multiple object types, including custom objects, in one call with API version 20.0 and later. For example, you could create a contact and an account in one call. You can create records for up to 10 object types in one call.
>
> Records are saved in the same order that they are entered in the sObjects input array. If you are entering new records that have a parent-child relationship, the parent record must precede the child record in the sObjects array. For example, if you are creating a contact that references an account that is also being created in the same call, the account must have a smaller index in the sObjects array than the contact does. The contact references the account by using an External ID field.
>
> You can't add a record that references another record of the same object type in the same call. For example, the Contact object has a Reports To field that is a reference to another contact. You can't create two contacts in one call if one contact uses the Reports To field to reference a second contact in the sObjects array. You can create a contact that references another contact that has been previously created.
>
> Records for different object types are broken into multiple chunks by Salesforce. A chunk is a subset of the sObjects input array and each chunk contains records of one object type. Data is committed on a chunk-by-chunk basis. Any Apex triggers related to the records in a chunk are invoked once per chunk. Consider an sObjects input array containing the following set of records:
>
> ```
> account1, account2, contact1, contact2, contact3, case1, account3, account4, contact4
> ```
>
> Salesforce splits the records into five chunks:
>
> - `account1, account2`
> - `contact1, contact2, contact3`
> - `case1`
> - `account3, account4`
> - `contact4`
>
> Each call can process up to 10 chunks. If the sObjects array contains more than 10 chunks, you must process the records in more than one call.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Adrian. Still I am getting error is: System.SObjectException: Field AccountId is not editable. How to update this, what I can think of is whatId or whoId of openActivities object, but how to use it, can you give any example what exactly are these fields?

Comment: Yeah I guess you would just change `put('AccountId', ...)` to `put('WhatId', ...)`.

Comment: Sorry Adrian I checked in workbench, even WhatId and WhoId fields are not updatable. Now, really confused, how to achieve this.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. I would look closely at the profile of your running user.